# How to do a fadein of an image on an Android Activity screen?

Tags: android, image-processing, fadein

I'd like to display a photo on an Android Activity screen with doing gradual and continual fade-in from pale monotone sepia to the final full color. I know how to do it on a Java Image/BufferedImage for the Graphic object but unfortunately I know nothing for the Android programming environment. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 82):

Hi Hiroshi you can do this for the fade in:

```
  ImageView myImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
  Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
  myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation); //Set animation to your ImageView
```

and inside your res\anim\ folder the animation file fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha 
            android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
            android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
            android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

but for the gradual fade in from  sepia to the full color, you must use [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

Comment: Works just fine. You probably won't need the `android:repeatCount="infinite"`, though...

Answer (score 52):

I wanted an image to fade (and then disappear) once clicked from full opacity to 0. Here is how I did it:

```
Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);

a.setDuration(1000);
a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
});

yourView.startAnimation(a);
```

Comment: thanks this helped me with an animation inside a recyclerview

Answer (score 7):

One method for this would be to use the animation set. See here;

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#animation

Some example code I have done (infinite loop fade out in this example) ;

In the animation .xml file;

```
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
       android:toAlpha="0.3"  
       android:duration="7000"
       android:repeatMode="restart"
       android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

In the java file;

```
 ImageView introanim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.introanim);
    Animation StoryAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.intro_anim);
    introanim.startAnimation(StoryAnimation);
```

You could fade from your sepia background/picture to whatever you want...

Comment: Thanks Jorge and Mike. I'll try your ways of doing.

Answer (score 1):

Another much simpler solution is to just put a stub onClick method to your ImageView you want to fade, then inside the method you add this:

```
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);      

/* Alpha attribute translates to opacity. 
A solid View means that the alpha attribute is set to 1 (which is the 
default) and completely invisible is 0 */
```