# Animating a background image

Tags: android, image, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with a tiled background. Is there a way to make a tween animation to fade out the existing image and fade in a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `startAnimation` to any of your views to start your animation.

Possible duplicate of this

[How to do a fadein of an image on an Android Activity screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597329/how-to-do-a-fadein-of-an-image-on-an-android-activity-screen)