# VideoView under LinearLayout, not visible

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, viewflipper, android-videoview

I add a `VideoView` to a `LinearLayout` and I can't make it to be visible on screen, `LinearLayout` is in front of it. After that `LinearLayout` is add to a `ViewFlipper` Here is my code:

```
    LinearLayout rr = new LinearLayout(this);
    rr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
    myVideoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    +"/download/"+"big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.bringToFront();

    rr.addView(myVideoView,new LayoutParams(rr.getWidth(),rr.getHeight()));
    vf.addView(rr);
```

Can anyone help me??? Please...Where is my mistake? I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that rr.getWidth/Height() are returning a size of 0 because they have yet to be measured.

getWidth/Height() returns the size of the view in pixels, as you have specified your layout params of rr to be fill_parent,fill_parent using getWidth/Height is unnecessary.

Try replacing

```
rr.addView(myVideoView,new LayoutParams(rr.getWidth(),rr.getHeight()));
```

with

```
rr.addView(myVideoView,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: you right...if I put like you sad it works but like this video appear suddenly and that is the problem...it must appear slow..I don't know how to explain better.

Comment: add an animation to the linear layout,such as a fade in, see the top answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597329/how-to-do-a-fadein-of-an-image-on-an-android-activity-screen.

Comment: I think it is a good idea but I didn't solve my problem yet :|