# How to fade in picture in ImageView loaded from url

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I would like to apply a fade-in animation to an ImageView to create the effect that the image, which is loaded from a url, fades in when the download is completed.

I know how to download an image from a url to an ImageView, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android), and I know how to apply a fade-in animation to an imageView [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597329/how-to-do-a-fadein-of-an-image-on-an-android-activity-screen).

This attempt

```
Drawable d = ImageUtils.fetchDrawable("the url");
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

results in a blink effect (see, not see, fade in to see). Reversing the order of the two last lines also results in a blink.

I've googled and searched SO for a solution in the form of a callback / listener - something like this:

```
imageView.setOnLoadCompleteListener...
```

to register the loading complete event in ImageView but I haven't found anything along those lines.

I'd be grateful for any pointers to a solution on how to implement this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the  `ImageView` visibility to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`
set `setAnimationListener` on your animation. and when the `onAnimationEnd`  change the visibility of the `ImageView`.

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

           // let make your image visible


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    });
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 33):

You can use: TransitionDrawable, simple code as follows:

```
        // Transition drawable with a transparent drwabale and the final bitmap
        final TransitionDrawable td =
                new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                        new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT),
                        new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap)
                });
        // Set background to loading bitmap
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(
                new BitmapDrawable(mResources, mLoadingBitmap));

        imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
        td.startTransition(FADE_IN_TIME);
```

Comment: This works great, if you have already another image in the ImageView as placeholder you can call getDrawable() and use it instead of the Transparent ColorDrawable which will create a transition between the two images.

Comment: To enable crossfading between 2 images use td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true), because crossfading is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the onPostExecute method of that answer you mentioned and trigger the animation there (when the image is actually loaded and ready):

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fadein);
    bmImage.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
}
```