# Fade in animation while loading image Using Picasso

Tags: android, fade, picasso, image-loading

I want to show a fade effect when image is loading on Imageview. I am using picasso to cache image and display in image view. I have searched alot for this but couldnt find any solution.

I have used earlier before and i know in some version they had .fade(int Duration) method to fade image while loading but i couldnt find this method anymore.

Here is what i am doing now

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(viewHolder.data.imageList.get(0).url)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.a_place_holder_list_view)
                .error(R.drawable.a_place_holder_list_view)
                .into(viewHolder.ivUser, context.loadImage(viewHolder.ivUser, viewHolder.data.imageList.get(0).url));


public Callback loadImage(RoundedImageView ivUser, String url) {
    return new callback(ivUser, url);
}

public class callback implements Callback {

    RoundedImageView imageView;
    String url;

    public callback(RoundedImageView imageView, String url) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        Picasso.with(BaseActivity.this)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.a_place_holder_list_view)
                .error(R.drawable.a_place_holder_list_view)
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.v("Picasso", "Could not fetch image");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Please help me i have been stuck in this for quite long time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/743 , see JakeWharton answer at the bottom. use a callback.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting Jake Wharton's answer [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/743):

> If the image comes from anywhere except the memory cache the fade
>   should be automatically applied.

If you check the [`PicassoDrawable`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/PicassoDrawable.java) class

```
boolean fade = loadedFrom != MEMORY && !noFade;
if (fade) {
  this.placeholder = placeholder;
  animating = true;
  startTimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
}
.
.
.
@Override public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
if (!animating) {
  super.draw(canvas);
} else {
.
.
.
```

`fade effect` is already applied for images loaded from n/w and not memory/cache
and `FADE_DURATION = 200f; //ms`

To force fade, again quoting jake wharton's answer [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/743):

> You can specify noFade() and then always play an animation in the
>   image loaded callback. You can also rely on the callback being called
>   synchronously to determine if an animation needs played.

```
final AtomicBoolean playAnimation = new AtomicBoolean(true);
Picasso.with(context).load(..).into(imageView, new Callback() {
  @Override public void onLoad() {
    if (playAnimation.get()) {
      //play fade
      Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
      fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
      fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
      imageView.startAnimation(fadeOut);

      Animation fadeOutPlaceholder = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
      fadeOutPlaceholder.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
      fadeOutPlaceholder.setDuration(1000);
      placeHolderImageView.startAnimation(fadeOutPlaceholder);
    }
  }
  //..
});
playAnimation.set(false);
```

Comment: fade effect is already applied to images loaded from n/w. Fade duration is 200ms. Otherwise as @Hourglass stated, specify noFade() and then  play an animation in the image loaded callback.

Comment: Define fade-out animation and apply inside `onLoad` callback. See updated answer for some hints.

Comment: What i want is when my image is loaded it fades from placeholder image to actual image. what this code does is after image is loaded it fades it .

Comment: You can have two overlapping image views. The target imageView alpha can be set to 0. The placeholder image view below it alpha can be kept at 1 and animation can be applied to both the imageviews with one changing alpha from 0 to 1 and the other from 1 to 0. Or you can use a transition drawable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416871/how-to-fade-in-picture-in-imageview-loaded-from-url Some ideas... I just provided some hints.

Comment: I dont understand the AtomicBoolean use. Why setting false immediatly after calling Picasso?

Comment: What's `playAnimation` for?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).fetch(new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                imageView.setAlpha(0f);
                Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
                imageView.animate().setDuration(300).alpha(1f).start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I do this:

```
Picasso.get().load(url).fit().noFade().centerInside().into(imageView, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    imageView.setAlpha(0f);
                    imageView.animate().setDuration(200).alpha(1f).start();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the setAlpha(0f); ?