# Picasso does not do the fade animation

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using Picasso to display some images and as the title says, the images just pop out, there's no fade animation. I'm using the version 2.5.2

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(url)
       .into(mTarget);
```

Is there any way to force it?

Thanks,

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488556/fade-in-animation-while-loading-image-using-picasso

Comment: Glide is recommended instead of Picasso. It has some advantages in terms of memory usage. It also supports GIF. But you can do what you want ;)

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks! It really helped me

Comment: @DennyWeinberg I've just tried Glide. It work exactly like Picasso. I mean it does not do the fade animation too when it loading from memory.