# Can't get image to fade in/out with different duration of time

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to fade my image alpha from 1 to 0 by 2000ms but it seems like it goes rather quickly like half a second. Here's my code:

```
ImageView tom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgJerry);

    tom.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
```

I'm following a lesson from Udemy and they got it work fine.

Comment: hope you find this link useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597329/how-to-do-a-fadein-of-an-image-on-an-android-activity-screen

Answer (score 0):

You should use Animation on it. Declare the animation in xml and its duration and then refer this in to Code.Yes previous answer is correct..
[How to do a fadein of an image on an Android Activity screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597329/how-to-do-a-fadein-of-an-image-on-an-android-activity-screen)

Answer (score 0):

For those who also face the same problem make sure that you turn on Animation in the developer setting in your android phone.

I've been turn it off for a while and just turn it back to 1x or 0.5x is enough.